# convert C# object to IOpenApiAny

Tags: c#, openapi, .net-core-3.0

I wish to set `OpenApiSchema.Example`. Which is an `IOpenApiAny`.

Can i convert/cast a simple c# object to an existing `IOpenApiAny`, ex. `Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiObject`? or i need to implement the interface on all my objects

**Example**

```
var schma = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiSchema
{
    Example = new MyObject();//doesn't work, how can i cast it?
};
```

Background: I am trying to create a Swashbuckle filter which adds examples to request and response parameters and schemas. I am using the upcoming Swashbuckle 5.0 (in beta) which is using OpenAPI.NET, so I am trying to create my filter using that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I wish to set OpenApiSchema.Example"? Please could you give a complete example? At the moment I'm finding it hard to understand your question.

Comment: `IOpenApiAny` is an interface. You don't convert objects to an interface, the object's class needs to implement the interface. [OpenAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification) is the "new" (2-year old already) name for Swagger anyway, so Swashbuckle already supports it, even if the names are different

Comment: Please post your code. Do you have some code that used to implement an older interface and now needs to implement IOpenApiAny ?

Comment: For simple examples you can use `TheSchema.Example = new OpenApiString("example here")`. There are many versions of the `OpenApiXXX` classes which you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/tree/vnext/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Any).

Answer (score 2):

Your class `MyObject` needs to implement [`IOpenApiAny`](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Any/IOpenApiAny.cs), as follows:

```
public class MyObject : IOpenApiAny
{
    // implement everything here that IOpenApiAny defines:

    public AnyType AnyType { get; }

    public void Write(IOpenApiWriter writer, OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

If you have lots of such classes, and you can come up with a common implementation for all of them, then you can use a single abstract base class and let all the concrete classes inherit from that:

```
public abstract class BaseObject : IOpenApiAny
{
    // implement everything defined by IOpenApiAny (see above)
}

public class MyClass1 : BaseObject
{
    // additional "MyClass1" methods/props
}

public class MyClass2 : BaseObject
{
    // additional "MyClass2" methods/props
}
```

Comment: Please refer to similar question where the exact implementation is shared.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515825