# Transitioning ISchemaFilter examples to Swashbuckle 5.0

Tags: c#, openapi, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

Before Swashbuckle 5 it was possible to define and register a `ISchemaFilter` that could provide an example implementation of a model:

```cs
public class MyModelExampleSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.SystemType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyModel)))
        {
            schema.Example = new MyModel
            {
                Name = "model name",
                value = 42
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The `Schema.Example` would take an arbitrary object, and it would properly serialize when generating the OpenApi Schema.

However, with the move to .NET Core 3 and Swashbuckle 5 the `Schema.Example` property is no longer an `object` and requires the type `Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.IOpenApiAny`. There does not appear to be a documented path forward regarding how to provide a new example.

I've attempted, based on looking at code within `Microsoft.OpenApi`, to build my own implementation of an `IOpenApiAny` but any attempt to use it to generate an example fails from within `Microsoft.OpenApi.Writers.OpenApiWriterAnyExtensions.WriteObject(IOpenApiWriter writer, OpenApiObject entity)` before its `Write` method is even called. I don't claim that the code below is fully correct, but I would have expected it to at a minimum light up a path and to how to move forward.

```cs
/// <summary>
///     A class that recursively adapts a unidirectional POCO tree into an <see cref="IOpenApiAny" />
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     <para>This will fail if a graph is provided (backwards and forwards references</para>
/// </remarks>
public class OpenApiPoco : IOpenApiAny
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The model to be converted
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _model;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="OpenApiPoco" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">the model to convert to an <see cref="IOpenApiAny" /> </param>
    public OpenApiPoco(object model)
    {
        this._model = model;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public AnyType AnyType => DetermineAnyType(this._model);

    #region From Interface IOpenApiExtension

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Write(IOpenApiWriter writer,
                        OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        this.Write(this._model, writer, specVersion);
    }

    #endregion

    private static AnyType DetermineAnyType(object model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            return AnyType.Null;
        }

        var modelType = model.GetType();

        if (modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(long))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(byte))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(byte[])) // Binary or Byte
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTimeOffset)) // DateTime
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime))       // Date
        )
        {
            return AnyType.Primitive;
        }

        if (modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable))) // test after primitive check so as to avoid catching string and byte[]
        {
            return AnyType.Array;
        }

        return AnyType.Object; // Assume object
    }

    private void Write(object model,
                        [NotNull] IOpenApiWriter writer,
                        OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        if (writer is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(writer));
        }

        if (model is null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        var modelType = model.GetType();

        if (modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(long))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(byte[])) // Binary or Byte
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool))
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTimeOffset)) // DateTime
            || modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime))       // Date
        )
        {
            this.WritePrimitive(model, writer, specVersion);
            return;
        }

        if (modelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable))) // test after primitive check so as to avoid catching string and byte[]
        {
            this.WriteArray((IEnumerable) model, writer, specVersion);
            return;
        }

        this.WriteObject(model, writer, specVersion); // Assume object
    }

    private void WritePrimitive(object model,
                                IOpenApiWriter writer,
                                OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        switch (model.GetType())
        {
            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)): // string
                writer.WriteValue((string) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(byte[])): // assume Binary; can't differentiate from Byte and Binary based on type alone
                // if we chose to treat byte[] as Byte we would Base64 it to string. eg: writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) propertyValue));
                writer.WriteValue(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[]) model));
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool)): // boolean
                writer.WriteValue((bool) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTimeOffset)): // DateTime as DateTimeOffset
                writer.WriteValue((DateTimeOffset) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime)): // Date as DateTime
                writer.WriteValue((DateTime) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double)): // Double
                writer.WriteValue((double) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float)): // Float
                writer.WriteValue((float) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)): // Integer
                writer.WriteValue((int) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(long)): // Long
                writer.WriteValue((long) model);
                break;

            case TypeInfo typeInfo
                when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid)): // Guid (as a string)
                writer.WriteValue(model.ToString());
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(model),
                                                        model?.GetType()
                                                            .Name,
                                                        "unexpected model type");
        }
    }

    private void WriteArray(IEnumerable model,
                            IOpenApiWriter writer,
                            OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            this.Write(item, writer, specVersion); // recursive call
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    private void WriteObject(object model,
                                IOpenApiWriter writer,
                                OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        var propertyInfos = model.GetType()
                                    .GetProperties();

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (var property in propertyInfos)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);

            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(model);

            switch (propertyValue.GetType())
            {
                case TypeInfo typeInfo                                        // primitives
                    when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))            // string
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(byte[]))         // assume Binary or Byte
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool))           // boolean
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTimeOffset)) // DateTime as DateTimeOffset
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime))       // Date as DateTime
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double))         // Double
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float))          // Float
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))            // Integer
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(long))           // Long
                            || typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid)):          // Guid (as a string)
                    this.WritePrimitive(propertyValue, writer, specVersion);
                    break;

                case TypeInfo typeInfo                                   // Array test after primitive check so as to avoid catching string and byte[]
                    when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)): // Enumerable as array of objects
                    this.WriteArray((IEnumerable) propertyValue, writer, specVersion);
                    break;

                case TypeInfo typeInfo                              // object
                    when typeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(object)): // Object
                default:
                    this.Write(propertyValue, writer, specVersion); // recursive call
                    break;
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to transition `ISchemaFilter` examples to Swashbuckle 5.0 so that the appropriate serialization rules are respected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have an example on the repo:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/9bb9be9b318c576d236152f142aafa8c860fb946/test/WebSites/Basic/Swagger/ExamplesSchemaFilter.cs#L8

```
public class ExamplesSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        schema.Example = GetExampleOrNullFor(context.Type);
    }

    private IOpenApiAny GetExampleOrNullFor(Type type)
    {
        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case "Product":
                return new OpenApiObject
                {
                    [ "id" ] = new OpenApiInteger(123),
                    [ "description" ] = new OpenApiString("foobar"),
                    [ "price" ] = new OpenApiDouble(14.37)
                };
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be functionally correct, but what scares me is the implication that the new normal totally ignores the configured serialization settings (eg property casing, enum and date handling, etc) and by its nature disconnects the tie to an actual model structure. Seems to be a step back in my opinion.

Comment: That comment is something you should add to the repo, here there is nothing we can do

Comment: Agreed, I'm not trying to imply blame, simply commenting current thoughts as I continue my investigation based on your response.